# Single click to open folders not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago. Single click to open folder option is not working. Both single click and double click work the same.

Answer (score 3):

Click the files icon located at the left side of screen. At the top of the screen there will be files activity.  Click that, then go to **Preferences** and on the behaviour tab you will find your single click option. Tick that and enjoy.

[image: dropdown menu from Files in top bar showing Preferences option 3rd]

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck **Use the new views** in **Preferences > Views > Experimental** and then select **Single click to open items** under the **Behavior** tab.